# sql table udt, vs 2008, csharp

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

I am trying to run a SQL stored proc from Visual Studio 2008 which takes a table-valued UDT parameter as an input.  I added this parameter in Visual Studio 2008 but when I run this program it gets an "ArgumentException - Specified type isn't registered on target server."
So I googled this problem and think I need to create a new class in Visual Studio 2008 matching the properties of this table type from SQL Server 2008.  But I can't find any examples on the internet involving *table* UDT's.  And I tried all of the scalar UDT examples, but I wasn't sure how to modify these to make it table-based.
I also read I may need to create an assembly, although I don't know if this is required only for importing a type into SQL Server 2008 or if it can also be used to import a type into Visual Studio.  BTW, I do not see any types listed from the Server Explorer in VS 2008, although I do see the database and its SP's.  I tried refreshing the database, but the types were still not showing.
What I need to do is simple.  I have a table UDT like so:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[parseInputFile] AS TABLE(
[NumCols] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[strRow] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

And the code snippet from my C# code is:

```
    public static int AppendData(string[] myStringArray)
    {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.uspAppendTableFromInput";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@InputFileParam", SqlDbType.Udt);
            param.UdtTypeName = "AdventureWorks.dbo.parseInputFile";
            param.Value = myStringArray;
            conn.Open();
            RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

RowsAffected show zero rows affected after running this.  What am I missing?  Can u point me to a website demonstrating a simple example of this.  Or else give me a tip?  I have also tried 'param.UdtTypeName="parseInputFile";' for the above snippet, but this returned the same error.  BTW, "myStringArray" is essentially a table.  It is a series of strings.  e.g. myStringArray[0] = "Hello|Bob|How|Do", myStringArray[1] = "I|Am|Fine|And", etc.

Comment: example @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337864#337864

Comment: What does your stored proc look like? Mostly the list of parameters you've declared

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Call the stored proc with a set of parameters in the user-defined table type? Or call the stored proc to get such a table RETURNED from it?? Not quite clear...

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you got your setup almost right - halfway through :-)

Check out those introductory articles to TVP's - table-valued parameters- which is what I *GUESS* you're trying to use, right?

- SQL Team: [SQL Server 2008 Table Valued Parameters](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters)
- ADO.NET team blog: [Introducting Table-Valued Parameters Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/08/15/introducing-table-valued-parameters-part-1.aspx)

Basically what you need to do is this:

- create a user-defined table type - you have that already
- create a stored procedure which takes on of those table types as a READONLY input parameter (not sure if you got this - haven't seen your code yet)
- to call from .NET; you need to create a DataTable instance and re-create the same structure (in terms of fields and their types - shown in the SQL Team article)
- fill that DataTable
- create a SqlConnection and SqlCommand (of CommandType = Stored Proc) in .NET which defines that table-type parameters as of type "SqlDbType.Structured" in .NET, and sets its values to the DataTable created above
- call that stored proc (packaged in the SqlCommand) from .NET

Does that help at all? I'd strongly recommend the SQL Team article - very informative!

Marc

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Marc!  I just posted another question regarding this same problem.  I had some trouble with this website so I published it as a different question.  Would u please look at that other question?  Should be easy to find, since I've only posted two questions to this website now.  Thanks.